# Broken dpgk? Failure running script /usr/sbin/dpkg-preconfigure --apt || true

Tags: 14.04, apt, dpkg

Ubuntu Server 14.04

```
apt-get install <package>
```

produces the error:

```
E: Waited for /usr/sbin/dpkg-preconfigure --apt || true but it wasn't there     
E: Failure running script /usr/sbin/dpkg-preconfigure --apt || true
```

dpkg seems to be installed, see:

```
$ sudo apt-get install dpkg                                      
Reading package lists... Done                                                   
Building dependency tree                                                        
Reading state information... Done                                               
dpkg is already the newest version.                                             
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

How can I repair this package?

I tried

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall dpkg
```

but of course this action produces the same error.

Answer (score 1):

this means there is some problems in your configuration scripts since the `DPkg::Pre-Install-Pkgs {"/usr/sbin/dpkg-preconfigure --apt || true";};` doesn't exist so you have to  create it.

Try this command to create it:

```
sudo sh -c "echo 'DPkg::Pre-Install-Pkgs {"/usr/sbin/dpkg-preconfigure --apt || true";};' >> /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/70debconf"
```

---

To do it in steps:

open the /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/70debconf

```
 gksudo gedit /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/70debconf
```

Add this line and save it:

```
DPkg::Pre-Install-Pkgs {"/usr/sbin/dpkg-preconfigure --apt || true";};
```

Now try again

Comment: Thanks for this advise. I saw this on another thread.  HOwever, there seems to be an error in the syntax.  It produces an error

Comment: > sudo sh -c "echo 'DPkg::Pre-Install-Pkgs {"/usr/sbin/dpkg-preconfigure --apt || true";};' >> /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/70debconf"
--apt: 1: --apt: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
sh: 1: true;};' >> /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/70debconf: not found

Comment: Check the update