# Failure running script /usr/sbin/dpkg-preconfigure --apt || true

Tags: apt, dpkg

I did all steps from here [Broken dpgk? Failure running script /usr/sbin/dpkg-preconfigure --apt || true](https://askubuntu.com/questions/615674/broken-dpgk-failure-running-script-usr-sbin-dpkg-preconfigure-apt-true/879442#879442)
but it doesn't work. What Can I do else? when I try `dpkg --configure -a` it shows:

```
dpkg --configure -a

dpkg: error: "if { test "$DPKG_HOOK_ACTION" = add-ar chitecture || test "$DPKG_HOOK_ACTION" = remove-architecture; } && test -x /usr/ share/pkg-config-dpkghook; then /usr/share/pkg-config-dpkghook update; fi", state -1
```